# Display Headings in Parallel in footer.php

Tags: php, html, css

I am using the following line of code to display some stuff in `footer` of my `html` page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<body>
    <div class="linksc" id="link_container" style="text-align:left;padding:20px 0;width:940px;margin-right:1000px;margin-left:10px;">
            <div class="links">
                <u>
                    <li>Site Navigation</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ's</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sell on ULTABUY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="links" style="text-align:left;padding:20px 0;width:940px;position:relative;left:300px; top:20px">
                <ul>
                    <li>How Site Works</li>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">How Does ULTABUYWork?</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Shipment and Delivery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Returns and Warranties</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Payment Methods and Security</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Protection and Prevention</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Technical Information</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
<?php

    echo "<p>Copyright &copy 2012</p>";
?>
```

I want to display the links for `Site Navigation` and `How Site Works` in parallel(currently they are being displayed as one below the other).How can I do that ?? Thanks and Regards.

Comment: I don't think you should echo your `"<p>Copyright &copy 2012</p>";` after the `</html>`. You should put this right before the `</body>`. Furthermore you should put `;` after `&copy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `float:left` to the style of first div and `float:right` to second.

Comment: what if I have 3-4 headings ?

Comment: you can use a table layout with single row and multiple colomns.

Comment: is there any other way apart from float ?? I want to display How Site Works in the centre and not in the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
display:inline-block;
float:left;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jYARF/)

EDIT:

without float here:

[New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jYARF/1/)

Comment: is there any other way apart from float ?? I want to display `How Site Works` in the centre and not in the right.